# Using FormControl or ngModel in NgFor (Angular6)

Tags: angular

Angular 6:

Displaying a List

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let list of lists">
    <div class=card>
      <h2>{{list.name}}</h2>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of list.items">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
      ///.... add an item to list (code below see all options)....
    </div>
```

Add Item to list: Option 1

```
<input type="text" #addItemTitle>
<button [disabled]="!( addItemTitle.value.length > 4)" 
(click)="addItem( addItemTitle.value )">Add Item</button>
```

Details (option 1): Doing this for last 3 months and it works perfectly fine. Now i want to add validation. Value update occurs only when clicked outside input box.

Add Item to list: Option 2

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="addItemTitle">
<button [disabled]="!(addItemTitle?.length > 4)" 
(click)="addItem( addItemTitle )">Add Item</button>
```

Details (option 2): Problem here is all ngModels behave as one, so updating updates all others (bcz. ngModel is same), same goes for FormControlDirective

Add Item to list: Option 3 (Currently using)

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="addItems[i]">
<button [disabled]="!((addItems[i])?.length > 4)" 
(click)="addItem( addItems[i] )">Add Item</button>
```

Details (option 3): This is what i am currently using, i declared addItems = [] in component.ts, it works.

**My Concerns:**

1. Stability: Is option 3 good..any other suggestions.
2. Extensible: I have to edit/delete items as well, thus nested ngfor in ngfor, so addItems= [] will not work,
   I may have to declare addItems = [[]], addItems[i][j]
3. Since, my main aim is validation. FormControlDirective offers great validation control, but addItems = [a,b,c], where a, b,c are new FormControl, but i dont know the number...

Edited:

I have found a better solution: Using component, create an extra component called InputHandlerCmp pass data to it, using @Input and changes. This way
seperates each ngModel or FormControlDirective (better validation)

Comment: Maybe [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) are helpful